# tkinter, save the input as variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use the input value as variable and this is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
Label(window, text='Cavity number').grid(row=0)

CavNum = StringVar()

for i in range(1,8) :
   globals()['L{}_CavNum'.format(i)] = StringVar()
   globals()['L{}_CavNum'.format(i)] = Entry(window, textvariable=globals()['L{}_CavNum'.format(i)])
   globals()['L{}_CavNum'.format(i)].grid(row=0, column=i)

window.geometry("1200x150")

window.mainloop()
```

everytime I do print(L1_CavNum), it says "<tkinter.Entry object .!entry>". please tell me what is the problem

Comment: I believe `StringVar`s have a `text` field or something that you can use to access their text. The printout you're seeing is the default object string representation. Also, you really shouldn't use `globals` like that. Just create a dictionary, or even just a list of `StringVar`s.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-using the same name for the entry widget as you use for StringVar. You could simply change `globals()['L{}_CavNum'.format(i)] = StringVar()` to `globals()['L{}_CavNumSV'.format(i)] = StringVar()` and `print(L1_CavNum)` to `print(L1_CavNumSV.get())`. However the .get() function will execute when your code runs so you will have to have a button or another event to callback the function.

I would do it like this.

```py
from tkinter import *


def print_vars():
    for x in range(len(cavity_string_vars)):
        print(cavity_string_vars[x].get())


window = Tk()
Label(window, text='Cavity number').grid(row=0)

cavity_string_vars = []
cavity_entries = []

for i in range(7):
    cavity_string_vars.append(StringVar())
    cavity_entries.append(Entry(window, textvariable=cavity_string_vars[i]))
    cavity_entries[i].grid(row=0, column=i)

print_button = Button(window, text="Print", command=print_vars)
print_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.geometry("1200x150")

window.mainloop()
```

To me associated arrays are much easier than naming each variable even when you program it as you have. Perhaps that is needed for your case.